# tailwind css - can't get item to fill out page, always stuck in smaller container

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make my page look similar to this https://dash.blinq.app/onboarding/personal-details

Currently with this code, I am getting really bad flex styling using tailwind, i can't seem to work out how to get it to fix properly.

```
    import { ChevronRightIcon, HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

const pages = [
  { name: 'Privacy', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Customizations', href: '#', current: true },
  { name: 'Details', href: '#', current: true },


]

function BreadCrumbs() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex" aria-label="Breadcrumb">
      <ol className="flex items-center space-x-4">
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#" className="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
              <HomeIcon className="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
              <span className="sr-only">Home</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <li key={page.name}>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <ChevronRightIcon className="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
              <a
                href={page.href}
                className="ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700"
                aria-current={page.current ? 'page' : undefined}
              >
                {page.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </nav>
  )
}

  



export default function Example() {
    return (
      <div className="min-h-screen bg-white flex">
          <div className="hidden lg:block relative w-6/12 flex-auto">
          <img
            className="absolute inset-0 h-full   object-cover"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505904267569-f02eaeb45a4c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1908&q=80"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:flex-none lg:px-20 xl:px-24">
        <BreadCrumbs/>

          <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-lg lg:w-96">
            <div>
           
              <h2 className="mt-6 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Welcome to Moodmap</h2>
              <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600">
              Let's get you started!

              
              </p>
            </div>
  
            <div className="mt-8">
             
  
              <div className="mt-6">
                <form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6">
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Email address
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                      <input
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        required
                        className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div className="space-y-1">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Password
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                      <input
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        required
                        className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
               
  
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                    >
                      Next
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
```

which looks sort of like this.

[image]

How do i get the flex to allow the forms to fit properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a [MCVE]?

Comment: Yeah I mean, the above code is able to be rendered as a page in react as is

Comment: Fix the codesandbox to showcase your problem. Right now I faced an `Internal Server Error`

Comment: @LeCoda without a working sandbox link, we cannot work with your code. Your codesandbox link produces an "Internal Server Error" as aloisdg mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you want Login form and breadcrumbs to take larger space.

- Reduce the image from half the screen size to 1/3 size (Remove w-6/12 flex-auto).
- Remove lg:flex-none on second div.
- Remove width limitation on the login box (Remove max-w-lg lg:w-96 )

and that should get the form flex to remaining 2/3 space.

```
import { ChevronRightIcon, HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

const pages = [
  { name: 'Privacy', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Customizations', href: '#', current: true },
  { name: 'Details', href: '#', current: true },


]

function BreadCrumbs() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex" aria-label="Breadcrumb">
      <ol className="flex items-center space-x-4">
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#" className="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
              <HomeIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
              <span className="sr-only">Home</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <li key={page.name}>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <ChevronRightIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
              <a
                href={page.href}
                className="ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700"
                aria-current={page.current ? 'page' : undefined}
              >
                {page.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </nav>
  )
}

  



export default function Example() {
    return (
      <div className="flex min-h-screen bg-white">
          <div className="relative w-4/12 lg:block">
          <img
            className="absolute inset-0 object-cover h-full"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505904267569-f02eaeb45a4c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1908&q=80"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center flex-1 px-4 py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-20 xl:px-24">
        <BreadCrumbs/>

          <div className="w-full ">
            <div>
           
              <h2 className="mt-6 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Welcome to Moodmap</h2>
              <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600">
              Let's get you started!

              
              </p>
            </div>
  
            <div className="mt-8">
             
  
              <div className="mt-6">
                <form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6">
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Email address
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                      <input
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        required
                        className="block w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div className="space-y-1">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Password
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                      <input
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        required
                        className="block w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
               
  
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="flex justify-center w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                    >
                      Next
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
```